# Win 8, T-Bird 17.0 JPG attachments do not open

Tags: windows-8

I've attached a JPG from my 'My Pictures' folder to an e-mail (*sic.* in Thunderbird?), but it will not open before sending, nor after.

Message -

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\App data\local\temp\xxxxx.jpg cannot be opened because the associated helper application does not exist.
```

What do I change where?
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bug with Thunderbird I would report it to through the proper channels.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall you get the option from that point of choosing which program should be used to open the file.  So select one and use it.